# MS SQL 2008 stored procedure problem and vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

This has been stumping me for a few days now.

I have a stored procedure on a MS SQL 2008 server. I can connect through management studio and as the user I am using in my code and execute the stored procedure and it works how I expect it to. The problem comes in when I try to use it in my code. Here is my code:

```
 Dim strConn1 As String = "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=user;Password=pass"
 Dim objconn1 As New SqlConnection(strConn1)
 Dim objCommand1 As New SqlCommand("storedProcedure", objconn1)
 objCommand1.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
 objCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strEncounter", Encounter)
 objCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NetworkName", Employee)

 objconn1.Open()
 Dim test = objCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery()
 objconn1.Close()
```

When I run this it does nothing. There is no exception, no error, and the variable test which stores the number of rows affected from the method ExecuteNonQuery is 1. When I check the database to see the row it should have inserted there is nothing.

The other really strange thing is that I have the same code in an ASP.NET website and it works fine. I have copied it and pasted it exactly the same into this application which is a forms application and it will not work. Thanks.

Comment: Can you run SQL Server Profiler to see if the stored procedure is at least being called?  Also, is there a transaction in the stored procedure that could be rolling back?

Comment: ... or post your stored procedure so we can work with every variables of your question.

Comment: I don't think a rollback could have taken place, as according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx), that would return -1.  Profiler is the best thing to start with.

Comment: I will have to see if our DBA can do the profiling for this. The DB server has a lot of traffic on it.

Comment: Great, let us know what happens and if it is indeed being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you are using `ExecuteNonQuery`, "nothing" should happen in the application. `ExecuteNonQuery` says that an action is going to be performed on the SQL Server, and do not expect a returned result set.

Now, if you are expecting a result set, you have to use a DataAdapter and .Fill() a DataTable object with the results:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(objCommand1)
da.Fill(dt)
```

You'd only want to use ExecuteNonQuery when you are inserting, updating, or deleting rows. When you want to read data to the client app, you have to store it somewhere. As a side note, this is an argument against copy-n-paste coding ;) Also, it's arguably out of fashion to use bastardized Hungarian Notation (i.e. the "obj" prefix to your variables). It much more readable like this:

```
Dim connString As String = "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=user;Password=pass"
Dim cn As New SqlConnection(connString)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("storedProcedure", cn)

cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strEncounter", Encounter)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NetworkName", Employee)

cn.Open()

Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
da.Fill(dt)

cn.Close()
```

Everything prefixed with "obj" makes it harder for the eye to pick out the variables.

Comment: The question was about an insert, and he also correctly states that [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) should return an Int32 representing the number of rows affected.

Comment: As far as copying and pasting goes I pulled a working block of code and pasted it into this application and it does not work. Nothing else is changed other than it runs on a webserver and this is a client application.